# Handle pan, zoom and click with both Mouse/Touch on Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, delegates, pan

I'm working on a 2D turn based game and I'm in the condition to handle mouse and touch.

The game has an hexagonal map and requires pan, zoom and click action.

I decided to apply delegate-pattern so each object that requires an action, sends the event to its delegate who will do or not stuff.
In this way all inputs converge to a TurnManager that, with a state machine, handles events in accordance to the current game state.

Example:
`MapCell.OnMouseUpAsButton()` calls
`delegate.OnCellClick(MapCell)`

All works well and in this way I can handle **when** do **something**.

The problems arrived when I started to implement *Zoom* and *Pan* in the map.
For these two actions, I had to avoid classic *Monobehaviour* method (*OnMouseDown*, *OnMouseUpAsButton*, ...) and use *LateUpdate*.

So,
I created a *CameraHandler* that in the *LateUpdate* uses:

- *HandleMouse()*
- *HandleTouch()*

and, using delegate pattern, evokes the actions below:

- *OnMapWillPan()*
- *OnMapPan()*
- *OnMapEnd()*

To avoid Pan or Clicks over UI elements, *TurnManager* filters received events with `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`

**Problem**
On Mac/Mouse all works great! :D
On smartphone/Touch I can't click on nothing and only Pan is working. The debug on device is infernal because the lack of breakpoint or console.

**Questions**

- Do you ever handle this things? How?
- Which approach did you use?
- What do you think I'm doing wrong?
- Are there best practices to avoid problem like this and handle correctly crossplatform input?
- Are there any good lecture/book for this argument?

PS: if needed I can show the code

Comment: Maybe you should post the current pan, zoom and click code. Many would be willing to look at it and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: good point. Is a lot of code and I have to summarize it. I'll edit the question adding it later